# imagemagick crop image 1-indexed

Tags: image, macos, imagemagick, zsh, imagemagick-convert

I want to crop a 960x1080px image into 6 480x360px chunks.

This worked:

```
convert backdrop1.jpg -crop 480x360 backdrop1tile%d.jpg
```

But the image naming (`%d`) starts at zero.

How can I make the first "tile" be called 'backdrop1tile1.jpg' (and the last 'backdrop1tile6.jpg'), how do I get it to start at 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
convert backdrop1.jpg -crop 480x360 -scene 1 backdrop1tile%d.jpg
```